# Power supply current rating

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I've been researching my problem but really everything I found is complicated and I don't understand it. I bought a GPU with a requirement of a 400W power supply with 12V current rating of 22A.

[image]

Here's what it says on my power supply. Can I run the GPU on it?

Comment: What's a GPU in words?

Comment: Probably not...

Comment: Combined power on the 12 V rails = 250 W so 20.8 A. Seems like an old PSU where the 3.3 V and 5 V were more important than today. Get a new PSU. It might work but it probably won't be good for the PSU.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be better suited on the Super User or Server Fault exchanges, but I'll try to answer here anyway.

Without knowing more about the GPU you're wanting to use, it's unlikely that the power supply will work with it. The 12V power appears to be split between two different outputs (one has 10A rating, the other has 13A rating). There is no simple way to combine the outputs to get the 22A required by the GPU. Note: do not wire them together yourself -- this seems like a simple solution, but it will likely damage the power supply.

If your GPU has two separate inputs for the 12V power, then you might be able to use that power supply. But without knowing more about the GPU (i.e. manufacturer and model), then it's not easy to give a definitive answer.